# How to handle with same id in different onChange function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
handleselectenquiryId(e) {

    let attribute = document.getElementById(e.target.value);
    let sectorattrribute = attribute.getAttribute("data-items");
    this.setState({ enquiryId: e.target.value }, ()=>{
        let data = {
        id : sectorattrribute
    }
    UserAction._getSingleEnquiry(data);
    });


}

handleselectBookingId(e) {

    let attribute = document.getElementById(e.target.value);
    let sectorattrribute = attribute.getAttribute("data-item");
    console.log(sectorattrribute);
    this.setState({ bookingId: e.target.value }, ()=>{
        let data = {
        id : sectorattrribute
    }
    UserAction._getSingleBooking(data);
    });

}

<div className="col-sm-4 col-6">
         <h2 className="card-inside-title">Enquiry Id</h2>
             <select className="c-select form-control box_ip" onChange={this.handleselectenquiryId.bind(this)} value={this.state.enquiryId}>
          <option value='-1' disabled>Select Enquiry</option>
     {this.state.enquirieslist.enquiries.map((el) => <option id={el.enquiryId} data-items={el.id} value={el.enquiryId}>{el.enquiryId}</option>)}
             </select>
     </div>
  <div className="col-sm-4 col-6">
        <h2 className="card-inside-title">Booking Id</h2>
         <select className="c-select form-control box_ip" onChange={this.handleselectBookingId.bind(this)} value={this.state.bookingId}>
  <option value='-1' disabled>Select Booking</option>
             {this.state.bookinglist.bookings.map((el) => <option id={el.bookingId} data-item={el.id} value={el.bookingId}>{el.bookingId}</option>)}
    </select>
       </div>
```

I am having two dropdowns which has values 1 and 2 in both select tags.

data-items and data-item attribute i am maintaining in both respectively as both `el.id` is unique when onChange of `handleselectBookingId` it is taking the id of `handleselectenquiryId` onchange,

May I know what was the error i was doing.

As i was handling document.getElementById is this the proper way to work or any way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not good to use document.getElementById(e.target.value) in react as it has ref for acessing DOM nodes.

you can use ref in your case like this:

first, assign a ref to your options:

```
<select className="c-select form-control box_ip" onChange= 
 {this.handleselectenquiryId.bind(this)} value={this.state.enquiryId}>
      <option value='-1' disabled>Select Enquiry</option>
 {this.state.enquirieslist.enquiries.map((el) => <option ref={val => this[el.enquiryId] = val} data-items={el.id} value={el.enquiryId}>{el.enquiryId}</option>)}
 </select>
```

then access to their data-items attribute value like this in your onChange handler:

```
 this[e.target.value].attributes['data-items'].value)
```